# On change change date of all date picker in bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using 3 date picker on change of each date picker I need to change all the date picker. For e.g. if I select 10th August in first date picker it should change as 1st August in all date picker. If I change 10th of August in 2nd date picker it should change in all datepicker as 10th of August.

Here is my code:

```
<input  name="start" class="date_picker  form-control" id='from_one' type="text" />
<input class="date_picker form-control" id='from_two'  name="start" type="text"  />
<input class="date_picker form-control" name="end" type="text"  id='from_three'/>

$('.date_picker').datepicker({
  setDate: new Date(),
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: '-0m',
  minDate: 0,
  onSelect: function(text, dt) {     
    var secondDate = new Date($(".date_picker").datepicker("getDate"));
    var date2 = new Date(secondDate.getTime());
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate());
    $("#from_one").datepicker("setDate", date2);
    $("#from_two").datepicker("setDate", date2);
    $("#from_three").datepicker("setDate", date2);
  }
});
```

Its working but on change of 2nd date picker it takes the value of 1st date picker

Here is my demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvdurai/kGjdL/1514/)

Comment: can't understand if 1st date picker  select date 1 Aug thene 2nd date picker date will be ?
explain in ex.

Comment: change onSelect function with this: onSelect: function(text) {     
 $("#from_one").datepicker("setDate", text);
$("#from_two").datepicker("setDate", text);
$("#from_three").datepicker("setDate", text);
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to accomplish, this should work for you.

```js
$('.date_picker').datepicker({
  setDate: new Date(),
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: '-0m',
  minDate: 0,
  onSelect: function(text, dt) {
    var selectedPicker = this;
    var datepickers = $(".date_picker");
    var secondDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    var date2 = new Date(secondDate.getTime());
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);

    $.each(datepickers, function(index, value) {
      if (value !== selectedPicker) {
        $(value).datepicker("setDate", date2);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input name="start" class="date_picker  form-control" id='from_one' data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
<input class="date_picker form-control" id='from_two' name="start" type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
<input class="date_picker form-control" name="end" type="text" id='from_three' />
```